# Accepted means of positioning in-line CSS buttons?

Tags: html, css, button

What is the best (most elegant, efficient and universal) means of positioning multiple buttons in CSS? I would like to put the buttons in a line on the top right corner of the page.

I am using CSS3 in this case- if there are common ways of doing this in other versions, please list those as well!)

Right now, I am manually positioning different buttons as such:

```
.but1 {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:102px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
a.but:link {color:#FF00FF;}    /* unvisited link */
a.but:visited {color:#000000;} /* visited link */
a.but:hover {color:#FF0099;}   /* mouse over link */
a.but:active {color:#66FF33;}  /* selected link */
a.but:focus {color:#FF9900 }
}
.but:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #ffffff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #e9e9e9 5%, #ffffff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#ffffff');
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
.but:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
/* This button was generated using CSSButtonGenerator.com */


.but2 {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:102px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 130px;
    top: 10px;
a.but:link {color:#FF00FF;}    /* unvisited link */
a.but:visited {color:#000000;} /* visited link */
a.but:hover {color:#FF0099;}   /* mouse over link */
a.but:active {color:#66FF33;}  /* selected link */
a.but:focus {color:#FF9900 }
}
.but:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #ffffff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #e9e9e9 5%, #ffffff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#ffffff');
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
.but:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
.but3 {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:102px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 250px;
    top: 10px;
a.but:link {color:#FF00FF;}    /* unvisited link */
a.but:visited {color:#000000;} /* visited link */
a.but:hover {color:#FF0099;}   /* mouse over link */
a.but:active {color:#66FF33;}  /* selected link */
a.but:focus {color:#FF9900 }
}
.but:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #ffffff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #e9e9e9 5%, #ffffff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#ffffff');
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
.but:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
.but4 {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #e9e9e9 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e9e9e9');
    background-color:#ffffff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:102px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 370px;
    top: 10px;
a.but:link {color:#FF00FF;}    /* unvisited link */
a.but:visited {color:#000000;} /* visited link */
a.but:hover {color:#FF0099;}   /* mouse over link */
a.but:active {color:#66FF33;}  /* selected link */
a.but:focus {color:#FF9900 }
}
.but:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #ffffff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #e9e9e9 5%, #ffffff 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#ffffff');
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
.but:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

I feel as though this solution is clumsy and inefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you've used absolute positioning?

Comment: create one class for all the different css properties and re-use the class over different elements?

Comment: No particular reason- it got the job done for the present. I would be glad to change it in favor of something better.

Comment: It's highly dependent on a number of factors, such as the purpose of the buttons, and how they should interact with the rest of the DOM. There isn't any universally correct answer. Using `position: absolute` is acceptable (and recommended) in some cases, but in other cases `display: inline-block` would be a better option.

Comment: I highly suggest having a read in this document: https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css

Comment: Edited to narrow meaning to something easily solved. I would welcome more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things going on with your example as listed above.

This fiddle here addresses them all together:
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wWufG/)

First, nest your .but# classes since they are nearly identical:

CSS

```
.but1,
.but2,
.but3,
.but4 {
... code here ...
}
```

Also, you are missing a close brace after your .but classes, before your pseudo classes:

CSS

```
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
a.but:link {color:...
```

Should read as:

```
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
bottom: 0px;
}

a.but:link {color:...
```

You have created very WET code here... try and simplify your life and Don't Repeat Yourself... nest the exact same buttons with all of the same properties (except for position rules) within a parent div that positions them as needed. Then you can move the entire block easily.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for now- I will let you know how everything turns out.